# На почту приходит спам с формы обратной связи

Tags: javascript, php, form, sendmail, спам

У меня на сайте существует форма обратной связи следующего вида:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" id="form">
   <div>                                     <!--Таких дивов 5 штук--> 
      <label>
      <input>
   </div>
   <div> <!--Тут у меня капча от яндекса-->  </div>
   <button action="submit"> Отправить! </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript файл:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener("submit", formSend);

async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let error = formValidate(form)

    let formData = new FormData(form);

    if (error === 0) {
        form.classList.add('_sending')
        let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            let result = await response.json();
            alert(result.message);
            form.reset();
            form.classList.remove('_sending');
            location.reload();
        } else {
            console.log('Ошибка')
            form.classList.remove('_sending')
        }
    }
}
```

В нём ещё есть код валидации полей, проверки капчи и прочее, я их намеренно не добавил, т.к. вопрос не об этом.
И сам файл sendmail.php:

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail -> setLanguage('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail -> IsHTML(true);
$mail -> Port = 465;

// Кому пиьмо
$mail -> addAddress('sapa@stroylink.su');    

// Тема письма
$mail -> Subject = 'Заявка из формы обратной связи!';

// Содержимое письма

if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Имя:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
}

if(trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Номер телефона:</strong> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>';
}

if(trim(!empty($_POST['email']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Почта:</strong> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
}

if(trim(!empty($_POST['message']))) {
    $body.='<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> '.$_POST['message'].'</p>';
}

$mail -> Body = $body;

// Отправляем
if (!$mail ->send()) {
    $message = 'Ошибка';
} else {
    $message = 'Данные отправлены!';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response)
?>
```

Суть в том, что несмотря на мои старания отсеять ботов - 25% гарантированно пишут на почту спам.
Конечно, я пробовал разные методы защиты:

1. Перво-наперво форма спрятана в поп-ап, что мне казалось отсеит часть роботов;
2. У меня есть невидимое пустое поле, при заполнении в которое чего-либо форма выдаёт ошибку;
3. У меня стоит капча от Яндекса (Гугл и того больше ботов пропускает), при незаполнении которой форма так же не работает;
   Кому интересно, можете проверить: [в самом низу каждой страницы лежит форма](https://raonsrv.ru)

В конце концов я совсем отчаялся и бросил кнопку `<button>` в комментарий, чтобы прверить что я всё делаю правильно и проблема точно не во мне, а в капче или невидимом поле - но как же я был удивлён когда в течение дня, на почту, мне всё-равно пришло 3 спам-сообщения с моей формы:

[image: Пример спам-сообщения]

И да - я в конце-концов вообще удалил `<button>` из кода, но спам-сообщения это не особо волнует, спам как приходил, так и по сей день приходит. В интернет пространстве пытался узнать технологию работы спам-роботов, спрашивал у ChatGPT что можно добавить в форму, искал ролики на ютубе - всё бестолку, дальше капчи и пустого невидимого поля никто ничего не предлагает.

Люди добрые, дайте пожалуйста наводку что я делаю не так. Я бы не задавал сюда вопрос если бы всё не перепробовал и совсем не опустились руки - у меня в голове не укладывается, БАНАЛЬНО - как можно отправить собщение на почту без триггера **submit** в кнопке?? Если представляется возможным - напишите какой код можно изменить или добавить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "как можно отправить собщение на почту без триггера submit в кнопке" Сделать curl-запрос с типом POST с данными полей.

Comment: @u_mulder, Хорошо, подскажите пожалуйста, как защитить форму от такого рода запросов?

Comment: @InDevX, Всё это супер, но для меня как для незнающего то что вы говорите `ловить сабмит и делать обычный ajax запрос` - непонятно. Я лишь хочу огородить почту от роботов. Вопрос - как? Приведите, пожалуйта, код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу как использовали google recaptcha, после чего спама не стало (уже более 7 месяцев):

1. в head:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=[TOKEN]"></script>
<script>
    const grecaptcha_exec = function(f) {
        grecaptcha.execute('[TOKEN]', {action: 'homepage'}).then( f );
    };
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha_exec( function(token) {
            // console.log(token);
        });
    });
</script>
```

2. отправка формы:

```
<form method="post" action="/sendForm" id="contactForm">
  <input name="g-token" type="hidden" value="">
  ...
  <input type="button" value="Send" id="submit" onclick="return sendMail();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendMail() {
    // сперва проверка полей формы

    grecaptcha_exec( function(token) {
      $('#contactForm').find('input[name="g-token"]').val(token);
      sendMailNext();
    });
  }

  function sendMailNext(){
    $.post('/app.php?module=mail&action=send', {
      name: name, // поля с формы
      email: email, // поля с формы
      message: message, // поля с формы
      'g-token': $('#contactForm [name="g-token"]').val()
    }, function (response) {
      // проверка ответа
      $('#contactForm [name="g-token"]').val('');
    });
  }
</script>
```

3. обработчик формы (/app.php?module=mail&action=send):

```
$ip         =  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$token      =  trim($_POST["g-token"]);
$secretKey  =  '[SECRET]';
$url        =  "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".urlencode($secretKey)."&response=".urlencode($token)."&remoteip=".urlencode($ip);
$request    =  file_get_contents($url);
$response   =  json_decode($request);

if ( !$response->success ) {
    log("grecaptcha validation failed, bad token: $ip");
    echo json_encode(false);die;
}
elseif ($response->score < 0.5) {
    log( sprintf("grecaptcha validation failed: score=%s, ip=%s", $response->score, $ip));
    echo json_encode(false);die;
}

log(sprintf("grecaptcha validation success: score=%s, ip=%s", $response->score, $ip));

// отправка email

echo json_encode(true);die;
```